# Call parent instance's method inside of child instance

Tags: python

What's the best way of having a child class (B) instance call one of its parent class (A) instance's  methods? Passing `self` into the instance of the child class (B) seems to work, but somehow that doesn't seem to be efficient or good practice. Any better ways of going about this?

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.instanceOfB = self.B(self)
        self.name = name

    def hello(self):
        print 'Hello '+self.name

    class B():
        def __init__(self,parent):
            self.parent = parent

        def hi(self):
            self.parent.hello() ##Call parent instance's method 'hello()' here

instanceOfA = A('Bob')
instanceOfA.instanceOfB.hi()
```

Should result in:

```
Hello Bob
```

`@classmethod` and `@staticmethod` only work if `A.hello()` does not depend on any information instantiated with class A

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you nesting classes?

Comment: Just a way of organizing objects, I guess? Besides limiting B being instantiated in A only, is there a difference between that and `class B(A)` that I am missing?

Comment: I thought it was just an indentation error, and then I saw `self.instanceOfB = self.B(self)`

Comment: `class B(A)` means that class B *inherits* from class A. Ie, that iy has the same methods/properties and can optionally override some of them or extend them with further functionality. Nesting classes means that each instance of class A has its own version of class B(not its own instance object of class B, but its own version of the class itself)

Comment: This is extremely poor design, not in any way related to OOD techniques. Don't try to fix it, but use a proper OO design instead!

Comment: @entropy that much I understand. But I want B to call the method of _instance_ A.

Comment: @SkyNT the answer and the "right" way to do it depends on whether you actually want `B` to inherit from `A`, or whether then are truly different classes.

Comment: @Mr E In my current case, A holds data as well as methods to operate on the data. B Holds data _about_ the data in A in such a way that it must also instruct A to call a method according to certain conditions.

Comment: @SkyNT see this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/python-nested-classes-scope In python nesting classes does not imply any special relationship between them. You're better off not nesting and passing an instance of A to B's constructor(as you're already doing anyway)