# Inner classes cannot see one another?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was implementing Graph in python, I had written a following code:

```
class k: 
    class Graph:
          def __init__(self,v): 
                 array=[Adlist() for i in range(v)] 
    class Adlist:
          def __init__(self):
                 head=[]
    def printgraph():
          for i in array:
                 print(i.head)
if __name__==__main__
     l=k()
     l.Graph(5) 
     l.printgraph()
```

After running the code section, I got an error 'Adlist is not defined.'

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What have you done to try to remedy the problem?

Comment: Yes I was not able to create object of Graph. It shows Adlist in not defined..

Comment: Please give us a [mcve]. As written, this raises a `NameError` on `__main__`, which I doubt is the problem you're asking about. And include the exception traceback in the question, don't just give us a vague description in a comment.

Comment: Does Graph do anything else besides hold `array`, and does `Adlist` do anything else besides hold `head`?

Comment: More than likely the problem is that `Adlist()` being a member of the class `k` must be referenced using a qualified name: either `self.Adlist()` or `k.Adlist()`. If it's something else, please improve the question.

Comment: @ktb That's not the only issue: if `printgraph` is to be an instance method, it needs `self` as a parameter, and then reference array as `self.array` (assuming that `array` would then become an attribute).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - reference inner class from other inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185472/python-reference-inner-class-from-other-inner-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short version is: You want `k.Adlist` here, not `Adlist`. It's similar to the fact that when you want to access an attribute, you need `self.spam`, not just `spam`, although the details are different.

---

The medium-long version is:

While a class body *does* create a namespace, it's not like a function's body.

In particular, the locals in a class body cannot be captured by classes or functions defined within the class body, the way function locals can be captured by classes r functions defined within the function body.

However, when the `class` statement is executed, the namespace of that class body becomes the set of attributes of the class object. So, you can access those variables through the class (or through any of its instances, but that isn't relevant here).

---

Meanwhile, there are multiple other problems with your code:

- `__main__` isn't defined anywhere. You probably meant `'__main__'`?
- The `array` that you create in `Graph.__init__` is just a local variable, which goes away as soon as `__init__` returns, so nobody can ever access it again. You probably wanted `self.array` here.
- The `head` in `Adlist.__init__` has the same problem.
- The `printgraph` function doesn't take a `self` parameter, so it can't be called as a method on a `k` instance.
- The `printgraph` function tries to access something named `array`, but there's nowhere it could get such a thing from. Sure, instances of the class `Graph` (if you fix the first problem) have an `array` attribute, but there's no connection between a `k` instance and any `Graph` instance. As far as that `k` object knows, there could be 300 `Graph`s, or none at all. Maybe you wanted this to be a method of `Graph`, not of `k`?
- `l.Graph(5)` creates a `Graph` instance and then immediately discards it. That isn't very useful.
- Calling `l.Graph` instead of `k.Graph`, while legal, is potentially a bit misleading—it implies to the reader that there's some kind of connection between the specific instance `l` and the `Graph`, but there really isn't.

Putting it all together:

```
class k: 
    class Graph:
        def __init__(self, v):
            self.array = [k.Adlist() for i in range(v)] 
        def printgraph(self):
            for i in self.array:
                print(i.head)
    class Adlist:
        def __init__(self):
            self.head = []

if __name__ == '__main__':
     g = k.Graph(5) 
     g.printgraph()
```

Of course this will just print five empty lists, but that's better than a `NameError` and another `NameError` when you fix that and so on…