# NameError -- can Python-Enums as inner classes not see each other?

Tags: python, enums, jupyter-notebook

In the following setting

```
from enum import Enum

#class Enum2(Enum):
#    bla = 1

class OuterClass:
    class Enum1(Enum):
        n1 = "v1"
        n2 = "v2"

    class EnumExtended(Enum):
        a1 = "w1"
        a2 = OuterClass.Enum1
        #a2 = Enum2

    def __init__(self):
        a = OuterClass.EnumExtended
        for e in a:
            print(e, e.value)
```

I get the error message "NameError: name 'OuterClass' is not defined", pointing to the line `a2 = OuterClass.Enum1`. Should `OuterClass` not be visible there? How could I otherwise reference `Enum1` at that place?

And to make things even more confusing, when I run the code in a jupyter notebook, after activating and using the definition of `Enum2` (which is commented out in the sample above) instead of `Enum1` and then switching back to `Enum1`, the error is gone, but returns after a restart of the jupyter kernel. Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185472/python-reference-inner-class-from-other-inner-class

Comment: Seems so, thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - reference inner class from other inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185472/python-reference-inner-class-from-other-inner-class)