# How to use an inner class as a type annotation in another inner class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes

I have the next structure of classes:

```
class Root:
    @dataclass
    class Leaf:
        pass

    @dataclass
    class Node:
        leaf: Leaf
```

The problem is **PyCharm** doesn't see `Leaf` class, I also tried to specify it as `leaf: Root.Leaf` and even `'Root'.Leaf`... There was same result.
How to declare a field type in the inner class if the type is another inner class? Is it possible in python?
**P.S.** I can make the `Leaf` class an inner of the `Node` class but I am interested in my example.

Comment: Did you try `'Root.Leaf'`?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy yes, however it doesn’t work too. PyCharm still highlights it as error

Comment: The issue is unrelated to dataclasses, and thus seems to be a duplicate of [Python - reference inner class from other inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185472/python-reference-inner-class-from-other-inner-class)

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa it's little another question, how to initialize a field by an object of another inner class. I ask about type annotations. Seems it's impossible in python

Comment: Using nested classes in Python is rarely a good idea. They don't do anything special (unlike in, say, Java), and they give you namespace headaches like this one.

Comment: Likely your design is a bit backwards, you probably want top-level class definition of  `Node`, and both `Leaf` and `Root` are special cases of  `Node`s (inheritance). But do you even need special classes for that? I think you should post the problem you are trying to solve. I understand the sentiment of putting classes inside of classes for namespacing reasons (since Python does not have a dedicated namespace construct), but you can create namespaces by using modules (files) as well.

Comment: @Шах Annotations are just additions for the programmer/reader without any semantics for the interpreter, i.e. they get completely, 100% ignored. Your code also does not work on a functional level, not only on level of the annotations. What you are trying to do is not possible.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa, I have another class structure that's similar to this, just I can't post a real business logic so created that sample

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa I see, thank you for answer. I just wanted to be sure it's really impossible

Comment: You could declare `global Leaf` as your first statement after `class Root:` but IMO that's a code smell and defeats your purpose for an inner class. That and your linter will probably hate you.

Comment: @Axe319 thank you for answer... You are right that's not elegant solution that I looked for. I've decided to keep a plain structure without inner classes (using of namespace `internal`)

Answer (score 1):

Normally you can't reference an inner class from another inner class, but for the purpose of type annotation you can make such a forward reference with a string:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Root:
    @dataclass
    class Leaf:
        pass

    @dataclass
    class Node:
        leaf: 'Root.Leaf'

print(Root.Node(Root.Leaf()).leaf)
```

This would pass static type checking and outputs:

```
Root.Leaf()
```