# Nested classes inside a class cannot acces varibale from each other

Tags: python, class, nested

Please take a look at the following snippet. You can understand what I am trying to do. The vlan_start of PairTwo class must be derived from the values of PortOne. How do I do that?

```
>>> class G8032:
...     class PairOne:
...         vlan_start = 1101
...         vlan_count = 600
...     class PairTwo:
...         vlan_start = G8032.PairOne.vlan_start + G8032.PairOne.vlan_count
...         vlan_count = 400
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in G8032
  File "<stdin>", line 6, in PairTwo
NameError: name 'G8032' is not defined
>>>
```

EDIT:
I have tried without `G8032` in `G8032.PairOne.vlan_***`. it still doesn't work.

Comment: Simply use `PairOne.vlan_start` etc, at the time `PairTwo` is being created `G8032` doesn't exist.

Comment: `PairOne` and `PairTwo` can (should) be outside classes, or even better, `Enums`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary This wouldn't work

Comment: With fixed attributes, you shouldn't calculate PairTwo.vlan_start: just assign it to 1701. Otherwise, make it a property, and you can obtain classes through e.g. `__class__`.

Comment: Why are you nesting these classes?

Comment: I need to define those classes inside G8032 class, it is important for the syntax which is used in some other file(which used this hierarchical information encoded via the python syntax - `x = G8032.PairOne.vlan_start`) in the project. Unfortunately I am not at liberty to post snippets from that file.

Comment: @Evert This wouldn't work as well as long as OP keeps using nested classes.

Comment: There is certainly a better pattern to do what you are doing. FactoryPattern perhaps?

Comment: @vanangamudi This syntax doesn't imply that `PairOne` is *defined* inside `G8032`

Comment: @Shiva: Can you provide a simple example, to apply factory pattern over here?

Comment: @DeepSpace: I know, but I can acces the values with that syntax.

Comment: Interesting, so the scope created by the nested class has no clue about its enclosing scope. Though the scope within `G8032` can still access `PairOne`.

Comment: some has down voted the question, I don't understand why. It is perfectly a valid question which has not been answere anywhere in SO to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary it's not that the nested class has no clue about its enclosing scope. The problem is that the enclosing scope is not completely defined yet.

Comment: @DeepSpace Not really, something like `x = PairOne` within `G8032` still works even though `G8032` is still being parsed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't nest these classes. When the line `vlan_start = G8032.PairOne.vlan_start + G8032.PairOne.vlan_count` is executed, the `G8032` class is not completely defined yet.

If you **absolutely** need to supporty the syntax you mentioned in the comments 
 (`x = G8032.PairOne.vlan_start`) then you *could* (but probably *shouldn't*) use the code below:

```
class PairOne:
    vlan_start = 1101
    vlan_count = 600


class PairTwo:
    vlan_start = PairOne.vlan_start + PairOne.vlan_count
    vlan_count = 40


class G8032:
    PairOne = PairOne
    PairTwo = PairTwo

print(G8032.PairOne.vlan_start)
print(G8032.PairTwo.vlan_start)
# 1101
# 1701
```

Comment: I think it is closer to how I want it to look.

Answer (score 1):

Why not doing something like this -

```
class G8032:
    pass

class PairOne:
    vlan_start = 1101
    vlan_count = 600
class PairTwo:
    p = PairOne()
    vlan_start = p.vlan_start + p.vlan_count
    vlan_count = 400


if __name__ == "__main__":
    g = G8032()
    g.PairOne = PairOne()
    g.PairTwo = PairTwo()
```

You may find this thread interesting - [Nested classes' scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/nested-classes-scope)

Answer (score 0):

If you need the mentioned syntax, you could use this:

```
class G8032:
    PairOne = type('PairOne', (object,), dict({'vlan_start': 1101, 'vlan_count': 600}))
    PairTwo = type('PairTwo', (object,), dict({'vlan_start': PairOne.vlan_start + PairOne.vlan_count, 'vlan_count': 400 }))

print (G8032.PairOne.vlan_start)
>>> 1101
```