# Use instance attributes of outer class instances in inner class

Tags: python, class, nested, inner-classes

I'm trying to append inner class instances into a list which is defined as an attribute of the outer class instances. However I get an "AttributeError: type object 'Outer' has no attribute 'Inner_list'". Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


#Create new outer class
class Outer():

    def __init__(self, name = "", n_users = 1):
        self.user_name = name
        self.num_users = n_users
        self.Inner_list = []

#Create new inner class 
    class Inner():

        def __init__(self, n = 1, P = 0, w = 1, t = 0):
            self.number = n
            self.power = P
            self.num_windows = w
            self.func_time = t

        def windows(self, w1 = np.array([0,0]), w2 = np.array([0,0])):    
            self.window_1 = w1
            self.window_2 = w2
            self.daily_hours = np.zeros(1440)
            self.daily_hours[w1[0]:(w1[1])]=np.ones(np.diff(w1))
            self.daily_hours[w2[0]:(w2[1])]=np.ones(np.diff(w2))
            Outer.Inner_list.append(self)

#Create new instance of outer class
Out_instance_1 = Outer("outer",300)

#Create new instance of inner class
Inn_instance_1 = Out_instance_1.Inner(5,7,2,5)
Inn_instance_1.windows([6*60,8*60],[18*60,23*60])
```

Python says that Outer object has no attribute "Inner_list", and that's true because I understand that "Inner_list" is an attribute of Outer instances and not of the Outer object. If i create an Outer_instance and type "Outer_instance.App_list" it shows an empty list, as I want. So the problem here is that I am not able to make the code append the Inner instances to the generic Outer instance within which it is defined. Any help will be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested classes' scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/nested-classes-scope)

Comment: There is no such a "generic Outer instance ". `Out_instance_1.Inner`, `Out_instance_2.Inner`, `Outer.Inner` all refer to the same class, there is no difference. That said, flat is better than nested. Whatever problem you are triying to solve there are probably better ways.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sure there can be also better ways, that's why I am asking. Anyway, yes, if I manually create (in the console) a new Outer instance and type "New_Outer_Instance.Appl_list" it shows me correctly the empty list that I want. But the problem is that if I try to do that with the script it doesn't work, because I don't know in advance the name of the "New_Outer_Instance", I just know that it will be an instance of the Outer class, and I thought that this code would make Python understand it but it doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: @FrancescoLombardi There is nothing for python to understand, neither `Inner` nor their instances are related to any particular instance of `Outer` so you cannot expect python to magically find one. They do not even need any instances of `Outer`to exist. Idea: try to solve the problem without nesting the classes, it is doing nothing but confusing you. For more ideas look at the answer by @AndreyF where an instance of `Outer` is explicitly attached to each instance of `Inner`.

Comment: The idea by @AndreyF worked perfectly, but still keeping the indentation of the inner class, otherwise it won't work. Why do you say that it is better to have not nested classes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is good programming but you can pass the outer class instance to the inner class instance and then accessing it from the inner class a field:

```
class Outer():

    def __init__(self, name = "", n_users = 1):
        self.user_name = name
        self.num_users = n_users
        self.Inner_list = []

#Create new inner class
    class Inner():

        def __init__(self, outer, n = 1, P = 0, w = 1, t = 0): # added outer to the constructor
            self.number = n
            self.power = P
            self.num_windows = w
            self.func_time = t
            self.outer = outer # added an 'outer' field

        def windows(self, w1 = np.array([0,0]), w2 = np.array([0,0])):
            self.window_1 = w1
            self.window_2 = w2
            self.daily_hours = np.zeros(1440)
            self.daily_hours[w1[0]:(w1[1])]=np.ones(np.diff(w1))
            self.daily_hours[w2[0]:(w2[1])]=np.ones(np.diff(w2))
            self.outer.Inner_list.append(self) # accessing outer object as a field

#Create new instance of outer class
Out_instance_1 = Outer("outer",300)

#Create new instance of inner class
Inn_instance_1 = Out_instance_1.Inner(Out_instance_1, 5,7,2,5) # pass the outer object to the inner object
Inn_instance_1.windows([6*60,8*60],[18*60,23*60])
```