# How works scope in nested class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import typing

class BotTypes:

    class DiscPropertiesObject(typing.Dict):
        x: float
        y: float
        xspeed: float
        yspeed: float
        xgravity: float
        ygravity: float
        radius: float
        bCoeff: float
        invMass: float
        damping: float
        color: int
        cMask: int
        cGroup: int

    class PlayerDiscPropertiesObject(typing.Dict):
        player_id: int
        properties: DiscPropertiesObject
```

Hello, I don't know what wrong is with line `properties: DiscPropertiesObject`. In python3 I get this error:

```
     properties: DiscPropertiesObject
NameError: name 'DiscPropertiesObject' is not defined
```

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: Try `BotTypes.DiscPropertiesObject`

Comment: Is there a reason you're defining those two classes inside another class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested classes' scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/nested-classes-scope)

Comment: @vb_rises this also doesn't works

Comment: Write `from __future__ import annotations` in the beggining. This works only for python 3.7+ version. [Docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/)

Comment: @PatrickHaugh On the begining I wanted use `from botypes.py import *` to import all classes but I searched and this is not allowed. Now I just import Botypes and use these types

Comment: @facehugger I have Python 3.6.8 version, I think that I don't understand enough python scope and I want to know what I do wrong.

Comment: @Janek Kowalski, there are answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765677/nested-classes-scope)

Comment: @facehugger thanks, I think I now understand what is wrong with this code.